# Dropdowns (site chooser, inbox, notifications, mod inbox) no longer use uniform styling

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

Until very recently the "site chooser" dropdown looked the same everywhere for me, approximately like this:

[image: Workplace main]

Just now I went to a meta site and saw weird meta-themed colors:

[image: Workplace meta]

Holy orange links, Batman!  That's new.

So I looked at some other sites, and even on main the chooser sometimes has varied colors seemingly derived from the site theme:

[image: EL&U main]

I tested in an incognito window (and not logged in) -- same styling.  Firefox.

After posting this (originally just about the site chooser) I discovered that the problem occurs with the global inbox, moderator diamond inbox, and achievements dropdowns too.  Here's the last of those:

[image: Beer meta, achievements]

(I can't show you either inbox right now without doctoring because privacy, but you get the idea I hope.)

Could we please have a return to consistency?  I *think* this is unintended, right?

Comment: Can reproduce the color changes, but not the weird scrollbar.

Comment: @Shog9 what's weird about the scrollbar?  That doesn't jump out at me as unusual.  (I'm using a Mac, by the way.)

Comment: Yeah, I figured :) Just having a bit of fun with that, since I tend to forget how different they look for in-page elements.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to remember whether maybe you previously didn't use the OS styling for the in-page elements, but I don't have an older screenshot handy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Great catch. Looks like some of our refactoring broke some overrides. We're pushing a fix now.

Comment: I assume this is from the same set of changes -- the tag styling still looks different on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @hichris123 is there a bug report for those tag stylings? Not seeing one, but maybe I'm missing it.

Comment: No, but I assumed it was from the same root cause as this bug. Guess not?

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278039/tag-and-link-styling-on-per-site-metas-has-changed