# Tag (and link?) styling on per-site metas has changed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

This might be related to [Dropdowns (site chooser, inbox, notifications, mod inbox) no longer use uniform styling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278003/dropdowns-site-chooser-inbox-notifications-mod-inbox-no-longer-use-uniform), but that was fixed last night and I'm still seeing this.  On per-site metas I now see a darker gray background for the standard four tags, like this:

[image: Mi Yodeya meta]

I don't have an older screen shot to compare to, but they didn't previously jump out at me so much.  I turned off Stylish to make sure it's not something I'm doing; no change.  This screen shot was taken in Firefox on Windows 7.

Also, I'm not certain, but I *think* those bright orange username links are new.  It looks like the same orange we were seeing in achievements on beta metas last night.

Is this intended behavior?

Comment: I guess this wasn't just SO only (I posted this on mSO) - [Required tag colors have changed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320543/required-tag-colors-have-changed)

Comment: @hichris123 oh, I hadn't seen your bug report.  But no, definitely not just SO.  Every child meta I've visited so far today looks weird to me.

Comment: [Meta.TeX.SE] not affected...

Comment: @MonicaCellio Typically we try to make required tags have a darker gray background than post tags to help visually distinguish them. I can lighten this background color if it's too strong though.

Comment: @Hynes I'm used to them being visually distinct; this is just *a lot more* visually distinct than I'm used to, so I thought it might be a mistake.  They're really jumping off the page at me today, so if you were to lighten it some I'd be quite happy. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ok. I'll get a change together and push it up later tonight.

Comment: @Hynes thanks!  I appreciate it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I've pushed a change tonight. The required-tags are now slightly darker than the normal post-tags. I had them the same at first, but they were too hard to distinguish easily. They are still lighter than before though. Is that better?

Comment: @Hynes thanks, yes!  Mi Yodeya Meta (the site in my screen shot) looks much better, as does Workplace.  Beta sites seem a little dark but better -- probably not worth tinkering unless others speak up.  You can slap a status-completed on this as far as I'm concerned.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Great to hear. Let me know if you see anything else.